# How do I plant lollipops?

Tags: candy-box-2

Seems different from original version where the planting happens once you get the key.

I cannot find any place to start planting, please help?

I have tried to plant lollipops in all 3 screens.

Answer (score 4):

Once you have...

> ...beaten the rat cellar, you will be given a world map. You can get to the world map by clicking 'back to map' at the top of the village.
>  Then you need to beat the desert level, and then the lollipop farm will become accessible on the map.